# Add i++ for each new row that will created by the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make some repeatable fields with PHP and Javascript. This works fine, but after saving the post (creating an plugin for WordPress) the cloned row will override the latest one. This is because I don't use unique id's for each row.

I want to add an 'id' attribute with javascript and I want for each row that is created with the id 1 increase. I had already done something similar with PHP, but found out that this is not what I wanted and I am better out with javascript, I think, because when I clone the field with the "add new" button the amount doesn't increase with +1;

Here is the php code that I had used:

```
$count = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    // Begin a table row
    echo '<tr class="row" id="' . '['.$i.']' . '-repeatable">';
    echo '<td class="order">' . '['.$i.']' . '</td>';

            // Do cool stuff inside the row

    echo '<td class="remove"><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>'; // End .row

} // End for loop

<a href"#" class="button">Add new row</a>
```

JS code for the repeatable fields:

```
// Add repeatable row
jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function() {
    // Clone row
    var row = jQuery(this).closest('.ui-sortable').find('tbody tr.row:last-child');
    var clone = row.clone();

    clone.find('input[type=text], text, textarea, select, input.upload_image').val(''); // Reset the values
    clone.find('.preview_image').attr('src', ''); // Reset the values

    row.after(clone);

    //
    return false;
});
```

I think I have to do something like this snippet of line:

```
clone.find('tr.row').attr('id', 'repeatable-' + addInteger);
```

But how do I increase with +1 inside Jquery/Javascript, like my example in PHP?

Comment: what are these ID's used for? Are they stored in DB ? They seem very arbitrarily created and if they are arbitrary why do you need them?

Comment: is easy to add them when no rows have been deleted, but once rows deleted need to know if a deleted ID can be reused or not, and need to make sure no duplication and need to know if server needs to generate ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is look at the ID of the row you're cloning and use that ID to give the new row its proper index value.  I added two lines of code to your example, one defining a new variable called `clonedIdIndex` and one using the value in that variable to define a new ID for the cloned row.

```
jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function() {
    // Clone row
    var row = jQuery(this).closest('.ui-sortable').find('tbody tr.row:last-child'),
        clone = row.clone(),
        clonedIdIndex = parseInt( clone.find('tr.row').attr('id').split('-')[1], 10 );

    clone.find('input[type=text], text, textarea, select, input.upload_image').val('');    
    clone.find('.preview_image').attr('src', ''); // Reset the values

    // Assign new ID
    clone.find('tr.row').attr('id', 'repeatable-' + (++clonedIdIndex));

    row.after(clone);

    //
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The id is not defined yet, so what a was saying I would like to add the Id to the tr class row. Only one question left, wat is [1] meaning and then the 10?
`attr('id').split('-')[1], 10 );`
So can I just change that snippet row with `.attr('id', 'repeatable').split('-')[1], 10 );`?

Comment: SO with the `split` function, you split an existing string into an array of substrings by a delimiter you specify as a parameter. In this case, the dash is our delimiter, so as long as as all your IDs have the form of something like "repeatable-[number]", you'll have an array of two elements. The first slot in the array [0] should contain the string "repeatable" and the second slot in the array[1] should contain the ID of the row you just cloned.

Comment: As for the 10, whenever you use the parseInt function, you have to specify two parameters. The first parameter is the string you want to convert. The second parameter is the radix that you will use so that JavaScript knows as to what base you want to convert the string. In this case, you want to just convert the string to base-10.